# Не выводит айди всех участников (Discord py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Есть простенький код (написал для проверки)

```
@bot.event

async def on_ready():
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            id = member.id
            print(str(id))
```

Бот уже на двух серверах, а выдает только свой айди.

Answer (score 0):

Переходите на [сайт](https://discord.com/developers/applications/)

 Выбираете своё приложение, переходите во вкладку `Bot`, включаете 2 галочки как на скрине[image: введите сюда описание изображения]